# Find a substring in a case-insensitive way - C#

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case insensitive contains(string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

With `Contains()` method of String class a substring can be found.
How to find a substring in a string in a case-insensitive manner?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the IndexOf() method, which takes in a StringComparison type:

```
string s = "foobarbaz";
int index = s.IndexOf("BAR", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); // index = 3
```

If the string was not found, IndexOf() returns -1.

Answer (score 15):

There's no case insensitive version. Use [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) instead (or a regex though that is not recommended and overkill).

```
string string1 = "my string";
string string2 = "string";
bool isContained = string1.IndexOf(string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is generally used for more "programmatic" text like paths or constants that you might have generated and is the fastest means of string comparison. For text strings that are linguistic use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Comment: If you run the measure-command speed of this vs the OrdinalIgnoreCase option the toupper()/tolower()..   converting all strings to lower case and then doing a standard indexof() w/out ordinalignorecase, the tolower() version is about 25% faster on both big and small strings.

Comment: But takes more memory, as the ToLower/ToUpper needs to allocate memory for new strings. Granted, everything needs to be taken into account.

Answer (score 7):

Contains returns a boolean if a match is found. If you want to search case-insensitive, you can make the source string and the string to match both upper case or lower case before matching.

Example:

```
if(sourceString.ToUpper().Contains(stringToFind.ToUpper()))
{
    // string is found
}
```

Comment: This generates two additional strings, one for each ToUpper, which results in more memory usage. Best way is to use the IndexOf overload that takes a comparer.

Answer (score 2):

`stringToSearch.ToLower().Contains(stringToSearchFor.ToLower())`

Comment: This generates two additional strings, one for each ToLower, which results in more memory usage. Best way is to use the IndexOf overload that takes a comparer.

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = "someTextorMaybeNot";
myString.ToUpper().Contains( "text".ToUpper() );
```

Comment: This generates two additional strings, one for each ToUpper, which results in more memory usage. Best way is to use the IndexOf overload that takes a comparer.